# Laravel Eloquent model query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I Want To Achieve the right query in laravel if anyone can help

I have This query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ((`is_verified` = 1) AND (`first_name` like '%%' or `middle_name` like '%%' or `last_name` like '%%' or `email` like '%%'))
```

and i have this in my code

```
$user->where([
                ['is_verified', '=', 1]
            ])
                ->where('first_name', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%$search%");
```

but it produces

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ((`is_verified` = '1') and `first_name` like '%%' or `middle_name` like '%%' or `last_name` like '%%' or `email` like '%%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an anonymous function in a "closure-where" clause.

```php
$user->where([
                ['is_verified', '=', 1]
            ])->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('first_name', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%$search%");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use anonymous function like following code:

```
User::where(function ($query){
        $query->where('is_verified', 1);
    })->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('first_name', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%$search%");
    })->toSql();
```